# F# Ninject Constructor Injection

Tags: f#, ninject

Is it possible to do implicit constructor injection in F# using Ninject? If so, how?

I tried to put the `[<Inject>]` attribute on the type definition, but I got back an error that it's invalid.

Here is what I tried:

```
[<Inject>]
type Blah(x : ISword) =
```

Comment: This should be possible - can you edit your question & post the code, so we can see what you have. This will help people to tailor the answer to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Inject` attribute is for [Property setter injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) only. Constructor injection is implicit. Just create your bindings and then make a `kernel.Get<Blah>()` and `Blah` is created using constructor injection.

Comment: +1 This is correct. BTW (I just removed the `[Inject]` off the ctor in the sample on https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns in case **It is important to note that the [Inject] attribute can be left off completely. This means that the majority of your code doesn’t need to be aware of Ninject and won’t need to reference the Ninject namespace/libraries.** is a bit too TL; DR for people

Answer (score 2):

The spec allows this as follows:

```
class-type-defn :=

    type-name primary-constr-args_opt object-val_opt '=' class class-type-body end
```

where

```
primary-constr-args :=

    attributes_opt accessopt (simple-pat, ... , simple-pat)
```

As a result, you just need to change your code to

```
type Blah [<Inject>](x : ISword) =
```

Comment: +1 But you definitely shouldn't be doing this if you're using Ninject. Ninject has lots of ways via the `Bind` expressions to identify the correct constructor to use (in the unlikely event that it won't just do the right thing using the default constructor selection strategy).

Answer (score 1):

Here's Constructor Injection in F#:

```
type Foo(bar : IBar) =
    // class members etc. here
```

Any library that requires you to slap an attribute on the type in order to understand that, is doing something wrong; pick another library.

Comment: +1 See other comments; While Ninject does allow one to override the default selection policy via attributes on Methods it is definitely not recommended or idiomatic. NB Ninject _*doesn't* require this_ and [the docs](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) don't recommend it - in fact they go out of their way to state your actual code should be aiming not to refer to the container [and be container agnostic]. (Happy for any edits in there if you believe it is in any way misleading)